# Accessing personal assets if connected through service account to Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm connecting to the Earth Engine API through a service account :

```py
service_account = 'test-sepal-ui@sepal-ui.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
credentials = ee.ServiceAccountCredentials(service_account, 'test.json')
ee.Initialize(credentials)
```

but I cannot access my assets. when I try to execute :

```py
ee.data.getAssetRoots()[0]['id']
```

That should give me the root folder name of my assets. Instead I get the following error :

> IndexError: list index out of range

because the list is empty...

Is it a normal behaviour ? How can I access my assets ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a service account you cannot access directly the assets of your personnal account.

A nice trick is possible though.

Create a new folder in your assets
go to it's sharing preferences and add your service account as reader or writer of the folder

[image]

Then you can access the folder assets content via :

```py
folder = 'projects/earthengine-legacy/assets/users/username/folder_name'
assets = ee.data.listAssets({'parent': folder})['assets']
```

### Note

If you want to interact with the folder content you need to change the sharing parameters of its assset individually
The writer/reader sharing option of the folder does not extend to its content